Choose the right Statistical test in my case
I have a survey dataset where each participant answered 20 unique questions. I want to analyze the data statistically but am unsure which test to use: ANOVA, repeated measures ANOVA, or mixed-effects model?
the data i want to use for the statistical test is the question type and the response time.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16cwLFGaF4KqLvwYNjHIcCyHaWup8vSJpL7gOEqk_XPA/edit?usp=sharing
The hypothesis that i want to test is there an effect of the question type on the response time ?
the question type has 4 modalities, and the response time is a numeric value in seconds.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit your question to explain what hypothesis/es you want to test, & describe the data you've collected in more detail

Thank you. Actually i jut did it. @Scortchi

Thanks. "Question time" - a typo? So each participant answers 20 questions - is that 5 of each type, or 20 of the same type, or does it vary ... ?

yes each participant answers 20 questions from 5 of each type ( in random order). To be clear, there is a 20 questions displaying two texts in different way (question type) and in different lenght (5,10,15 or paragraph). And all the participants have a random order,but at the end, it's 20 questions to answer. @Scortchi

If you have no missing data and a fully crossed design, you can use repeated measures ANOVA but you still must meet the sphericity assumption. With an unbalanced design where any questions were skipped, you’d want a linear mixed model with question type as a level 1 fixed effect (possibly with random slopes) and a random effect of participant. You could also add a random effect for each question, but it may not be necessary. Note this is distinct from question type and models the variation in RTs across questions. Reaction time shouldn’t be too skewed so it shouldn’t cause too many issues as an outcome. Using ordinary ANOVA will ignore the correlations among the participants reaction times across questions and is generally not appropriate.
